# Magento 2.3.3 - How to setup theme after migrate M1 to M2?

Tags: luma-theme, setup, magento2.3.3

After successful migration theme setup not working, setup Magento luma theme not working.

Theme Setup :

[image]

My website look like:

[image]

Debug.log:

> main.ERROR: Unable to load theme by specified key: 'default/theme327k'
>   [] []

Note : **theme327k** is my magento 1 theme.

Comment: Can you please share more details , Not working is too generic to provide a solution

Comment: can you please attach some screens.

Comment: Pls check with my updated post

Comment: please also show error logs.

Comment: Please go to /var/reports folder and open the latest report file. Here you will get the clue.

Comment: @Oscprofessionals my log : main.ERROR: Unable to load theme by specified key: 'default/theme327k' [] []

Comment: @MohitKumarArora FYI https://justpaste.it/4yxg5

Answer (score 0):

Refereed Answer from  Stack Exchange @Khoa TruongDinh

1. Try clear the cache and run the bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy again.
2. To add new theme you need to turn in developer mode.
3. Sometimes new theme added to theme table in our database with param type=1 (virtual theme). Try to set it to 0 (physical theme). For example:

> mysql> insert into theme
>   (parent_id,theme_path,theme_title,preview_image,is_featured,area,type,code) VALUES ('1','MyVendor/Base','MyVendor Base', NULL, 0, 'frontend', 0, 'MyVendor/Base');

We can read more here:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3409 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2797

**Or**

check cms_page table in database and check if default/theme327k is set in custom_theme column then execute this query in phpmyadmin,

> UPDATE `cms_page` SET `custom_theme` = NULL WHERE `custom_theme` IS NOT NULL

I found records in the cms_page table referring to a non-existent theme.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Not working.....

Comment: You need to match core config table in DB of both the instances and match, there is something missing there.

Comment: May i know what is this error main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs shared by @zus, I think the theme name does not match with the name saved in the theme table.

To fix this, first run this:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%theme_id%'
```

It will show you the theme ID which is currently in use.

Now go to **theme** table and delete the entry with the theme ID of the previous step.

Now remove the content of **/var/cache** folder and recheck.

I hope it should solve your problem.

Comment: The sql command you given return -> https://snipboard.io/Lb5eC0.jpg my theme table -> https://snipboard.io/yAF8wt.jpg what i need to do?

Comment: Did you have the theme name **default/theme327k** in past?

Comment: Yes, my magento 1 theme

Comment: FYI -> https://snipboard.io/5vNxzV.jpg

Comment: Its reference is somewhere in the database. Either you have set it for some CMS pages or some products or categories. Please check and change it.

Comment: @zus, did you check it?

Comment: May i know what is this error main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:

Comment: This is not an error. This is just an entry in the log file which tells that cache has been flushed in Magento.

Comment: My Back-End & Front-End not working  and showing Blank White page. Log file showing above error, how to solve this error?

Comment: screenshot : https://snipboard.io/i2V4Bo.jpg

Comment: Give proper permissions and retry.